# I want to detect Hex numeric character value

Tags: android, c++, c

I am using C/C++ in Android Native. Then have problem like this:
I want to detect a hex numeric character value in a char array in C/C++ (hex numeric like (\x01,\x02 , ....) and it's display like a square in log). I cannot compare all hex numeric, it's complicated.
My problem is detected if its numeric and delete from the char array. Anyone have any ideas?
Sorry for my bad english, hope you guys can understand me. Thanks

Comment: [`std::isxdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isxdigit)? [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) with base 16?

Comment: `isprint` from stdlib.h?

Comment: every character value can be expressed in a hexadecimal fashion. do you mean special characters?